# Pass result from a function to another function on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have this function to connect to my DB and consult something in it.

```
function conn (text){  
var mysql      = require("mysql");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host     : 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    user     : 'xxxxxx',
    password : 'xxxxxxx',
    database : 'xxxxxxxx'
});

connection.connect();

var queryString = 'SELECT usuario.idUsuario FROM usuario WHERE usuario.nickname = ' + '"' +  text + '"';  

function getID(text, callback){
connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
  var id;
    if (err){ 
      callback(err, null);
    }else{
      for (var i in rows) {
          id = rows[i].idUsuario;
      }
      callback(null, id);
    }
});
}

var result;
    getID(text, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      result = content;
    }
});
connection.end();
};
```

Now, i need to get the result in other variable to use it in other functions inside my JS file. How can i get that value without get code inside the variable?

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to use callbacks or promises everywhere. http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: im using calbacks in the function getID, but maybe im doing something wrong with this callbacks

Comment: You need to return the value from your function using a callback too.

Comment: There is a problem with it, im started with JS just a few days ago and there's a lot of things that I dont understand. Im traying to make a bot to work in "slack" platform, and i need to use NodeJS and Howdy.ai Botkit. Can you explain me how to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `function conn (text)` is fetching data using callbacks, you need to carry that pattern all the way to the consuming code. I'm not sure what the "other functions" look like, but let's pretend one looks like this:

```
function awesomeFunction() {
  var sweetResult = conn('sweet nickname');
  alert(sweetResult);
}
```

`conn` is going to connect and issue a query to your db. You do *not* want to stop everything else and wait for the result to come back, you want the db library to call you when it has results, hence the callbacks. Since the database isn't stopping everything, control returns to your `conn` function, and then back to `awesomeFunction`, and passes to the next line `alert(sweetResult)`. But wait! You didn't return anything from conn, but more important, the database hasn't even called back with results yet!

So, you need `awesomeFunction` to look more like this:

```
function awesomeFunction() {
  conn('sweet nickname', function(err, sweetResult) {
    alert(sweetResult);
  });
}
```

Which means, `conn` needs to accept and use a callback too:

```
function conn (text, resultsAreInCB){  
  ...
  connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    var id;
    connection.end();
    if (err){
      resultsAreInCB(err, null);
    } else {
      for (var i in rows) {
        id = rows[i].idUsuario;
      }
      callback(null, id);
    }
  });
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you!, it works perfectly. After test it on my code i understood the way that it works.